# Does the order in which the Kronecker delta is in a tensor product situation matter?

Tags: tensor-calculus

I know that the Kronecker delta is used to raise and lower indices, but I am not certain if the order in which it is placed in an equation matters, what I mean is, for example:

Are the following two any different?

$$\delta^\mu _\nu x_\mu\hspace{5mm}  and \hspace{5mm}x_\mu \delta^\mu _\nu $$

I know the first one would give me $x_\nu$ but **I don't know if changing the order they are written in would give me the same answer.**

**Would there be any difference in a situation in which instead of using a Kronecker delta, a metric tensor, $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, was used?**

Answer (score 2):

No, the order doesn't matter. In general, things with indices are just *components* of tensors, so they are just numbers, so they commute (as far as the indices are of concern)

Comment: In addition, note that if the metric tensor is $\mathbf{\eta}$, then $\eta^\mu{}_\nu = \delta^\mu{}_\nu$: what you are using *is* the metric tensor in fact.